# Python timeout mechanism that can be used nested

Tags: python, nested, timeout, signals

I have the timeout mechanism in Python that is based on signals:

```
class TimeLimit(object):
    """
    A context manager that fires a TimeExpired exception if it does 
 not return within the specified amount of time.
    """

    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handler)
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, self.timeout, 0)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_DFL)

    def handler(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeExpired()
```

An example of the usage:

```
    try:
        with TimeLimit(timeout):
        ...
    except TimeExpired:
    ...
```

But this mechanism doesn’t work when nested, since the inner level cancels the interval time for the outer level. What is the best way to implement the timeout mechanism that can be nested?

Comment: Please show the code that's giving you a problem

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you. I added more details to the question, I hope it is clearer now.